# Azure account not logging in either using VS2013 or azure powershell

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure, visual-studio-2013

[login hangs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lne6F.png)

While I am trying to add my azure account to VS2013, it asks for credentials and after i input credentials, the dialogue box just vanishes and i am still not connected to the azure account. i have tried to do it through the server explorer node and manage azure subscription option, also while i have used azure powershell it hangs on the shown image.

I have VS2013 update 5 installed and azure sdk version 2.8 and 2.7 both have the same problem

Credentials are correct since i am able to access azure account using them from browser.

Comment: I have had this issue. I closed all the instances on Visual studio and opened a new one and tried and it worked. No idea why this happens though.

Comment: I have tried it so many times. It is still not working. Well the same thing works on other machines.